# Can Rails ActiveJob be used to enqueue a block of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Can Rails' new ActiveJob API be used to enqueue a block of code? Sometimes I don't want to generate a job and move logic there. It moves knowledge out of my model that I'd rather keep there.

Let me give an example in a project I'm currently working on. This is a little weird but it's letting me keep all the knowledge in my model.

```
# app/models/subscription.rb
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  def cancel
    CancelSubscriptionJob.perform(self)
  end

  def cancel_tasks
    # stuff that takes a long time
  end
end

# app/jobs/cancel_subscription_job.rb
class CancelSubscriptionJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(subscription)
    subscription.cancel_tasks
  end
end
```

I feel like I'm going around my elbow to get my !@# here. I guess the argument could be made that the `cancel_tasks` method belongs in the job, but I don't like that. I want to see the cancellation tasks in the model where I've been keeping the rest of this type of knowledge.

There's also the argument that none of this belongs in the model in the first place, but at some point in Rails I feel like all people are telling me to do is extract and extract and extract until I never get any actual work done.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically use some metaprogramming to build a subclass on the fly, which follows ActiveJob spec, but I think that's more confusion than you need.

I'd just create a thin ActiveJob that calls your model method, effectively a wrapper for it.

BTW There's also a good argument for keeping models thin and focused on persistence rather than the kind of business logic that you'd want to queue. In that case, extracting the business logic out of models is a good thing. Some people say you can use job classes to keep logic in, but personally I'd prefer to keep them thin too and instead have logic in [service classes](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services).

Comment: I definitely have a ton of business logic in my models. It seemed like the right place to put that stuff. I updated the original question with an example to make it more clear. I am currently using a bit of weirdness in order to keep everything in the model. You can see from the example why I felt like generating a job was an unnecessary step.

Comment: Well, there are good arguments for splitting out business logic from persistence in more complex apps/models, but yes it can be overkill sometimes. Leaving that aside, a good reason to isolate jobs is to help manage your queue deployment. I do agree it's anti-DRY to make a trivial wrapper as in your question; but otoh if you or someone else is is managing a live queueing system, it would be difficult if you have to dive into any arbitrary code to find where these jobs are being created. It's a lot cleaner if they are all in a folder like app/jobs.

Comment: @RyanBurnette the reason for extracting is because Classes (and methods) that have a single responsibility are easy to reuse and refactor. So think of "extraction" as an attempt to have each Class/method serve a single responsibility. This make future change easier (i.e. a more flexible system). So I do agree with mahemoff's words about service classes, but would emphasize the Single Responsibility Principle as the reason why. For your case, a SubscriptionTasksCancellingService might do well (and would be easier to replace in the future, as needed, than having to gut the Subscription model).

Comment: @pdobb Thanks that helps put things into perspective for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be acceptable to do as follows:

```
# app/models/subscription.rb
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  def cancel
    CancelSubscriptionJob.perform_later(self)
  end

  def cancel_tasks
    # stuff that takes a long time
  end

  class CancelSubscriptionJob < ActiveJob::Base
    def perform(subscription)
      subscription.cancel_tasks
    end
  end
end
```

This is the type of pattern one would normally use when the believe is that the only use case for a given class is going to be from within the context of another. (Or, at least from within the first class's namespace.)

By example, the above method implies that: `Subscription`'s instance methods can still refer to `CancelSubscriptionJob` directly, but to refer to the job outside of `Subscription` you'd have to namespace it as `Subscription::CancelSubscriptionJob`.

Anyway, I don't see why this would be a bad thing other than that other developers would likely expect this ActiveJob to appear in the */app/jobs/* folder (so might need to go hunting). But it is a fairly standard approach in general.

Comment: This looks like a better pattern for me. I'm also realizing that it's going to allow me to keep all the testing for the cancel_tasks stuff in the spec for the model too.